# Issue with reading millions of files from cloud storage using dataflow in Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Scenario: I am trying to read files and send the data to pub/sub

1. Millions of files stored in a cloud storage folder(GCP)
2. I have created a dataflow pipeline using the template "Text files on cloud storage to Pub/Sub" from the pub/sub topic
3. But the above template was not able to read millions of files and failed with the following error

   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Total size of the BoundedSource objects generated by split() operation is larger than the allowable limit. When splitting gs://filelocation/data/*.json into bundles of 28401539859 bytes it generated 2397802 BoundedSource objects with total serialized size of 199603686 bytes which is larger than the limit 20971520.`

**System configuration:**
Apache beam: 2.38 Java SDK
Machine: High performance n1-highmem-16

Any idea on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to this document (1) you can work around this by modifying your custom `BoundedSource` subclass so that the generated `BoundedSource` objects become smaller than the 20 MB limit.

(1) https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#boundedsource-objects-splitintobundles

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [TextIO.readAll()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html#readAll--) to avoid these limitations.